# Seeking genealogy software that will support multiple languages and RTL writing?

Tags: software-recommendations

I am home user that would like to maintain his family records and tree for 3-4-5+ generations back. I am looking for Software, not necessary free, that will support multiple languages and RTL writing together with presentation of genealogical history in the visual manner, convenient for adolescents and not professionals.

Comment: Related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/20098/246

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because our [help/on-topic] explicitly says that questions asking "Which genealogy software or website is “the best”" should not be asked.  There is a [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange for that.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the software packages have time limited free trials or functionality limited free trials. Download them all and try them out. What works for me may not suit your way of working. Some examples are Family Historian, Gramps, Roots Magic, Ancestral Quest, Legacy Family Tree. There are a lot more.

The RTL requirement is only met by a few of the available packages. I use Family Historian and that does have some RTL support.

Comment: RTL = right-to-left?

Comment: @JanMurphy That's the usual meaning.